# Simple Formula for float algorithm

Tags: math, modulo

I need to set an alpha value, which is derived of a float value.

I list the pairs of float:alpha below, and I hope you guys can give me a simple correlation:

```
Float:Alpha
0:0
6:0.5
12:1
18:0.5
24:0
```

The maximum float value is 24, alpha can't be more than 1.
Inbetween values should be something parabolic/sine-like, with high resolution.

I suspect that this all involves a modulo. Please help me!

It would be helpful if you could express the formula in Objective-C syntax.

Thanks

Edit: to make myself clear:
The left column is the input value, the right column is the output value.

Paraphrasing David:

"Hi, here is my input: 0, 6, 12, 18,24 and here is my output: 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0. I need to generalize a solution. Halp."

Comment: I could just be stupid, but what does "I need to set an alpha value, which is derived of a float value." mean?

Comment: How are you getting those key value pairs?

Comment: If you need something sine-like then maybe the `sin` function will help.

Comment: Besides having skipped math, I'm not a native English speaker either. What I mean is: given a set of doubles (that's what I actually meant), I need to calculate a result, that is limited between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Sjakelien: An the result consists of...? You need to formulate your question in the following way: "Hi, here is my input: `x, y, z` and here is my output: `a, b`. I need to generalize a solution. Halp." Otherwise, people like me will have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula I would use is:

```
CGFloat alpha = sin(radius / 24.0 * M_PI);
```

This gives 0 for 0 and 24, 1 for 12, and a proper sine wave for values in between.

Please note that 0.5 for 6 and 18 are not valid values for a proper sine wave. 0.707 is proper for a sine wave for 6 and 18.

Comment: 0.5 is valid for 6 and 18 if the sine-wave is centered around y=0.5 with an amplitude of 0.5.

Comment: This does it for me. I'll play around with Andrew's answer, to see what I've done wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndrewCooper True. My answer was based on a standard unit sine wave.

Comment: Now, If I would have a radius oscillating between 0 and 60, how would that influence the formula? Replacing 24 by 60 doesn't seem to do the trick. Please ignore me; I'm already happy.

Comment: If you want 0 and 60 to result in 0 and you want 30 to result in 1 then yes, replacing 24.0 with 60.0 should give you similar results.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I will review in the morning. I think I get the general idea. My eternal gratitude!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a sine-wave the formula you're looking for is:

```
-(cos(n * pi / 12) - 1) / 2
```

Where n is the value from 0 to 24.

Comment: Dear Andrew, if I do a 
-(void) setBackgroundColor: (double)radius {

    int myAlpha= -(cos(radius * M_PI / 12) + 1) / 2;
    NSLog(@"myAlpha= %i", myAlpha);
   }
I just get values of 0 and 1.

Comment: Because you're converting the output to an `int`.  You need to keep the floating-point result as a `double`.